# How to connect a Zebra TLP 2844-Z label printer to Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: python, windows, printing, zebra-printers

The title is the basic info. I made a Python program on my Windows 7 computer that prints out labels, and it works when I connect my own printer to it. However, I tried connecting a label printer that is the one I mentioned in the title, and for some reason it's not working. My device manager categorizes it as unspecified, and trying to print with it won't work. This is an old model that was discontinued, so I tried finding a driver for it. Even that didn't work. Does someone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pull down the driver for a GK420d printer. Basically all Zebra ZPL printers use the same driver. If that driver does not recognize your printer automatically just manually install the GK420d driver and point it at your printer.